# Kendo UI for Angular, not able to remove focus on page load. Leads to keyboard open on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a website https://www.itraveleo.com. It is on Angular 4 and we use the Kendo-UI for Angular controls. On an iPhone the keyboard keeps opening on the following pages on page load:

1. Homepage - when I click to go to homepage using the logo or using the menu item, the focus goes to the "To" combobox and the keyboard opens up. This does not happen on initial load of the website
2. Blog - click on the DREAM menu item. On this page, click on any blog. The focus again goes to the To combobox and the keyboard opens up.
3. Right below the heading of each blog (on mobile), the category and region is listed (e.g. North America / Asia, etc. and Cosmopolitan / Family Time / Outdoorsy, etc). Click on each of these one by one. Again the To combobox gets focus and the keyboard opens up

Tried multiple common fixes but nothing seems to work on the iPhone (activeElement blur, setting focus on another element)